# ML Pipeline for Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe (df) with the following structure:

**Data**

```
label pa_age pa_gender_category
10000 32.0   male
25000 36.0   female
45000 68.0   female
15000 24.0   male
```

**Objective**

I wanted to build a RandomForest Classifier for the column 'label' where column 'pa_age' and 'pa_gender_category' are the features

**Process Followed**

```
// Transform the labels column into labels index

val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("label")
.setOutputCol("indexedLabel").fit(df)

// Transform column gender_category into labels

val featureTransformer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("pa_gender_category")
.setOutputCol("pa_gender_category_label").fit(df)

// Convert indexed labels back to original labels.
val labelConverter = new IndexToString()
  .setInputCol("prediction")
  .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
  .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels)

// Train a RandomForest model.
val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
  .setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures")
  .setNumTrees(10)
```

**Expected Output from the above steps:**

```
label pa_age pa_gender_category indexedLabel pa_gender_category_label
10000 32.0   male               1.0          1.0
25000 36.0   female             2.0          2.0
45000 68.0   female             3.0          2.0
10000 24.0   male               1.0          1.0
```

**Now I need the data into 'label' and 'feature' format**

```
val featureCreater = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("pa_age", "pa_gender_category"))
.setOutputCol("features").fit(df)
```

**Pipeline**

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(labelIndexer, featureTransformer,
featureCreater, rf, labelConverter))
```

**Problem**

```
error: value fit is not a member of org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
       val featureCreater = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("pa_age", "pa_gender_category_label")).setOutputCol("features").fit(df)
```

- Basically its the step from converting data into label and feature
  format that I am facing trouble.
- Is my process/pipeline correct here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
val featureCreater = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("pa_age", "pa_gender_category"))
.setOutputCol("features").fit(df)
```

You can not call `fit(df)` here, because `VectorAssembler` does not have method `fit`. Do not forget to remove `.fit(df)` in `StringIndexer` and `IndexToString` also. After the pipeline initialization call your `fit` method on pipeline object.

```
val model = pipeline.fit(df)
```

Now pipeline goes through each algorithm which you provided into it.

`StringIndexer` does not have property `labels`, use `getOutputCol` instead of it.